# Chat Typing Indicators, Redux

Tags: feature-request, chat

There is a question [Typing Indicator in Chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124166/typing-indicator-in-chat) that proposed the idea of a typing indicator, but the answer was no "because I see no practical implementation of this", according to the accepted answer.

Well, I see a practical implementation:

- When a person starts typing, a new message that says:

  > so-and-so is typing...
- When they finish typing, the ellipsis turns into the actual message.
- If they stop typing, the message goes away.

What does everyone else think?

Comment: The highest-voted "no" answer in that question isn't mainly lamenting the lack of a practical implementation; it says `The main thing we should be asking ourselves is whether knowing when somebody else is typing will really have a significant enough impact on our behavior.` Not saying I fully agree with the arguments made, but *how to do it* doesn't really seem to be the question here

Comment: @Pëkka The last paragraph that was edited into it does mention that.

Comment: I think practical meant more of "useful." Typing indicators does not increase the usefulness of chat.

Comment: I'm not *completely* sure about that - but that argument should probably be made in that other question...

Answer (score 7):

An indicator like this is only really useful during a one-on-one conversation. In a chat room where there are a bunch of people talking at once, it's just a distraction. There's no telling if that person is responding to you or someone else, or even if they're responding to someone *at all*. Maybe they're just typing some random message.

As stated in the first line of the accepted answer there, knowing this information doesn't have any impact on our behavior. I can't possibly know if the fact that a user is typing is at all relevant to *me*. If I sit there and wait for everyone to stop talking, I'll never say anything myself.

Other things to consider:

- If multiple people are typing, who shows up? Showing each on their own line would get annoying and waste screen space. I'd also have to scan a list to see if a specific person is typing or not.
- People would start trolling chat rooms by leaving things in the box or adding and deleting a character over and over. We'd end up with people in eternal states of "I'm typing" and just lose a row of text.

Comment: I can think of situations where seeing an indicator *would* make sense - basically whenever people aren't idly posting random stuff, but having a focused discussion, when it matters what is said in what order (or, say, to wait for your counterpart to finish their argument). The two other things to consider are good points; perhaps the indicator could overlay the user icon to the right

Comment: @Lower to whom, the writer or the reader?